# Obtuse-angled triangle equation

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Give a obtuse-angled triangle and the obtuse angle is 105º. Find n such that the acute angles be the roots of the equation.

$$3\sec(x)+n\left(\frac{1}{\sec(x)}-\frac{1}{\csc(x)}\right)=3\left(\frac{1}{\sec(x)}+\frac{1}{\csc(x)}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

If $A,B$ are the rest two acute angles, we immediately have $A+B=(180-105)^\circ=75^\circ$

On simplification of the given expression, 
$$\frac3{\cos x}=3(\cos x+\sin x)-n(\cos x-\sin x)$$
$$\implies \frac3{\cos x}=\sin x(3+n)+\cos x(3-n)\ \ \ \  (1)$$

$$\implies 3=(3+n)\sin x\cos x+(3-n)\cos^2x \ \ \ \  (2)$$

Multiplying either sides by $\sec^2x=1+\tan^2x,$

$$\implies 3(1+\tan^2x)=(3+n)\tan x+(3-n) \ \ \ \  (3)$$

We could directly go to $(3)$ from $(1)$ dividing  either sides by $\cos x,$ but the terms in $(2)$ are closely related to [Double-Angle Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html) which immediately reminds me of [Tangent half-angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) formulae

Now, rearrange $(3)$ to  get a Quadratic Equation in $\tan x$ whose two roots are $\tan A,\tan B$

Now use [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) to find $\displaystyle\tan A+\tan B$ and $\displaystyle\tan A\cdot\tan B$

and then use Angle [addition formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html) of tangents in $\displaystyle\tan75^\circ=\tan(A+B)=\cdots$

Comment: @Ewin, We can use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360747/prove-that-the-tangent-of-75-degrees-equals-2-plus-the-square-root-of-3?