# How to find by hands $\arctan(\sqrt 3 + 2)$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

Solving an example with imaginary units.

$$\theta = \arctan(\sqrt3 + 2)$$
$$\theta = 75^o = 5\pi/12$$

Looking at the result maybe it has something to do with $45^o$ and $30^o$ angles. But how to derive the result by hands, if the only thing i have is $\sqrt3 + 2$

Comment: Use that $\tan^2(\theta) + 1 = \sec^2(\theta)$ and that $\cos(2\theta) = 2\cos^2(\theta) - 1.$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/360747/947379) (Probably a duplicate)

Comment: @ACB Arguable whether a duplicate.  I distinguish between verifying an answer and deriving an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

It's easy to find $\angle ABC=75^\circ$.

Comment: appreciate. it's beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

We will use the half-angle formula for tangent:
$$
\tan\frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} .
$$
We want to get $2+\sqrt{3}$.  Remembering the basic values of sine and cosine, I see that
$$
2+\sqrt3 = \frac{1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{\frac12}
= \frac{1-\cos\frac{5\pi}{6}}{\sin\frac{5\pi}{6}} = \tan\frac{5\pi}{12}
$$
and therefore
$$\arctan(2+\sqrt3) = \frac{5\pi}{12}$$

Comment: when you wrote $\frac{1+\frac{\sqrt3}2}{\frac1 2}$ you took $\theta = 60^o$ . But why? What leads to choosing exactly this value?

Comment: That is the one I already know with value $\sqrt{3}$ in it.  It seemed likely, since $\sqrt{3}$ was already in the problem.  Actually, I took $\theta = 75^\circ$ so that cosine would be negative.